# Forge Viewer Autodesk v7 THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined in THREE.PointCloudMaterial

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

FINAL EDIT: Using THREE.PointCloudMaterial is broken in Autodesk Forge Viewer v7. Stick to THREE.ShaderMaterial.

EDIT: The Forge Viewer I'm using has customized version of Three.js release r71 ([source](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer)) which is why I'm using outdated code.

EDIT2: I think the issue might be because map wants to use THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() instead of THREE.TextureLoader? When I use THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() I get a [new problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om6dv.png) where the image is undefined. Guessing it has to do with a callback function?

EDIT3: `THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined` goes away with Petr's answer, but the texture still isn't seen in Forge Viewer: [image]

Might be an issue related to `WebGL RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`?

Code (sorry for the mess):

```
var PointMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
            color: 0xFF0000,
            size: 5,
            map: "",
        })
new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '../img/epidemics.png', function onLoad(tex) {
            PointMaterial.map = tex;
          });
var geom = new THREE.Geometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
let up_to_down = -4.5
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         let left_to_right = -4.5
         for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
              for (let k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
              var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
              vertex.x = Math.random() * ((-0.5 + left_to_right) - (0.5 + left_to_right)) + (0.5+left_to_right);
              vertex.y = 0;
              vertex.z = Math.random() * ((-0.5 + up_to_down) - (0.5 + up_to_down)) + (0.5 + up_to_down);
              geom.vertices.push(vertex);
                }
            }
        }
var particles = new THREE.PointCloud(geom, PointMaterial);
```

**Edits stop here**

My goal is to introduce texture to my BoxGeometry Point Clouds.

Whenever I run the following code (or any code that uses map for texture), I get a warning in the console.

```
let geometryForShapes = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var materialForShapes = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
            map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '../data/toppng.com-particles-3000x2000.png' ),
            color: 0xffff00,
            transparent: false,
            opacity: 0.9,
            size: 10,
        })
particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometryForShapes, materialForShapes )
```

Console output: `THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined`

r121 documentation (I'm stuck on r71):

[PointsMaterial Doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial)

[Texture Doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture)

My question is, was the fault on me for using PointCloudMaterial? Is this a bug? Do I need to import something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `THREE.Material: 'map' parameter is undefined` error is coming from three.js, and it's related to this line of code:

```js
map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '../data/toppng.com-particles-3000x2000.png' ),
```

The [load](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r71/src/loaders/TextureLoader.js#L15-L34) method in three.js R71 does not return anything. The loaded texture must be retrieved from a callback function, e.g., like so:

```js
var materialForShapes = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
            map: ,
            color: 0xffff00,
            transparent: false,
            opacity: 0.9,
            size: 10,
        });

new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '../data/toppng.com-particles-3000x2000.png', function onLoad(tex) {
  materialForShapes.map = tex;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The message seems to have gone away in the console but the textures still don't appear. However, the textures appear just fine if I run three.js on its own (without Forge Viewer). See code in EDIT3 above

Answer (score 0):

Your material creation should be

`var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( params );`

Not sure why you're using PointCloudMaterial.
Also, PointCloud isn't a standard class in Three.js. The page you linked to recommends you use Points:

`var points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just made an edit. Forge Viewer uses an outdated release of Three.js. Unfortunately, PointsMaterial and Points are not recognized in Forge Viewer.

Comment: Huh, that's very outdated. Looking at their ["Support page"](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/support/get-help), they say their support team will look for the `[autodesk-forge]` tag, so hopefully one of them will come by and help you soon. How much are you paying for their service, if you don't mind me asking? Sounds like they're charging to use an outdated library that's free for everyone and to crowdsource their customer support.

Comment: Maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57229077/how-to-dynamically-update-three-js-pointcloud-overlay-in-autodesk-forge/57250916#comment101011106_57250916)?

Comment: Tried the link, but the problem persists. At the lab, we are using the trial version right now and have special access as researchers. Thanks again for trying. Hopefully someone from Autodesk sees this soon.

Comment: As far as using the outdated version of three.js, we're aware that this is an issue for many of our customers, but unfortunately it's extremely difficult to do this sort of upgrade. It's a long story but TLDR: Forge Viewer needed to customize/optimize a lot of the three.js internals (for perf. improvements) but three.js wasn't cleanly extensible. The two codebases now diverged so much that trying to merge them together is a PITA.